# How to find number of distinct values in each column using mysql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, distinct

I have a question to find number of distinct values in each column in mysql, I have around 12 columns in the table and want to find number of distinct values for each column. Please let me know the statements used in mysql.

Comment: Please describe table structure with some sample data, Describe what is your expected result. And provide what you have tried. Please read this for more https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do you think people help you with information given???  Please read this to learn how to ask a question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You would use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct col1),
       count(distinct col2),
       . . .
from t;
```